# Get number of selected items in Listview

Tags: c, listview, winapi

In C# I can do the following to get the number of selected items:

```
int i = listView1.SelectedItems.Count;
```

Is there a way to do this in Windows API, or should I do it manually (i.e loop through all of the selected items and increment a counter)?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why don't you want to use the listView1.SelectedItems.Count? (Or are you writing in a different language than C#?)

Comment: @Bernd Linde I initially had the "C" tag, but "al-Acme" has changed it to "C#".

Comment: I just rolled this edit back, so the question is tagged C again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [ListView_GetSelectedCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will do the job quite well:

> Determines the number of selected items in a list-view control. You can use this macro or send the LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT message explicitly.

Comment: But this message is for a ListBox, is it okay to use it with a ListView?